# MySql explode/in_array functionalilty

Tags: mysql

In my table I have a field with data such as `1,61,34`, and I need to see if a variable is in that.

So far I have this

```
SELECT id, name FROM siv_forms WHERE LOCATE(TheVariable, siteIds) > 0
```

Which works, with the exception that if the siteIds were `2,61,53`, and `TheVariable` was `1`, it would return the row as there is a 1 in 61. Is there anyway around this using native MySql, or would I need to just loop the results in PHP and filter the siteIds that way?

I've looked through the list of [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) in MySql and can't see anything that would do what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `find_in_set` function.

```
SELECT id, name FROM siv_forms WHERE find_in_set(TheVariable, siteIds);
```

Check [**Manual**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php) for `find_in_set` function.

Comment: A-ha! Perfect, thank you :) (Cant accept for 8 minutes)